# Creating controls on runtime with Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have this action for the "Touch Up Inside" event of a UIButton that should create a new UIButton right below the sender:

```
-(IBAction) cloneMe: (id) sender{

    if (!currentY) {
        currentY = [sender frame].origin.y;
    }

    UIButton *clone = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    CGRect cloneFrame = [sender frame];
    cloneFrame.origin.y += currentY + cloneFrame.size.height + 30;
    clone.frame = cloneFrame;

    currentY = cloneFrame.origin.y + cloneFrame.size.height;


}
```

It doesn't work and the new button is never displayed.  Anybody knows what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting [sender.superview addSubview:clone];

Answer (score 1):

You create button but don't add it to view hierarchy - you missing

```
[self.view addSubView: clone];
```

call or similar